# Create overline text

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to create a boolean algebra simplifier.

This will allow the user to input boolean algebra expressions with the standard notation:

- + for the OR gate,
- ⊕ for the XOR gate,
- • for the AND gate and
- overlines for the NOT gate.

I am coding my project with Windows Forms and C#. I am able to use the all of the symbols previously mentioned except the overlines.

I do not know of a method that I could use to create overlines over my expressions.

The overline should be able to go over multiple characters and there should be the ability to 'stack' overlines as can be done with Microsoft Word.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `FontStyle.Underline` ?

Comment: Is this not a feature for WPF as opposed to Winforms? I apologise for the lack of knowledge, I am a student trying to complete a project.

Comment: Just a note to say that the combining overline is rarely used (maybe in electronics it's more common). You could use a more "up to date" form  like `¬` or `~` (`!` is too specific, probably). Anyway, you can do something like: `TextBox.Text = "a" + "\u0305";` and you'll get `a̅`. It doesn't work well with more letters combined. For multiple letters, use the `"\u035E"` symbol: Combining double macron.

Comment: Can this method be used to create multiple overlines? Is there also a way to identify If a letter has an overline on? I need to be able to work out if there is an overline to perform De morgan's Law.

Comment: `bool result = [SomeString].Contains("\u035E");` If you were asking me about it. Remember to prefix a nick with `@` to ping someone.

Answer (score 2):

It's Character Number 773 in C# character set. so here is an example:

```
        string A = "X̅x̅";
        string B = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            B += (int)A[i] + " - ";
        }
```

I think typing this special character is a hard task by keyboard. there are some other notation to displaying boolean algebra expressions. (e.g ^,|,v,->,=>,<=>, ...)

Comment: This is a ['combining overline'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/305/index.htm). How can one move them __over__ the character instead of of __between__?

Comment: I haven't Seen any sample in Windows Form. Windows Form is not too flexible. if you can write you application in WPF there should be more functionality on Displaying texts : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.textdecorations?view=netframework-4.7.2